# LINQ (Dynamic): OrderBy within a GroupBy using dynamic linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, dynamic-linq

I had the following query using normal linq and it was working great (using anonymous type),

```
     var result = from s in Items
            group s by s.StartTime into groupedItems
            select new {groupedItems.Key, Items= groupedItems.OrderBy(x => x.Name) };
```

But using Dynamic Linq I cannot get it to order by within the groupby.

```
     result = Items.GroupBy("StartTime", "it").OrderBy("Name");
```

It states the Name isn't available. It is worth noting that if I take my OrderBy off, everything works great but items inside each "Key" are not ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question!

I simulated your situation by creating a class called Item.

```
public class Item
{
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and then created a basic list of items to do the groupby.

```
List<Item> Items = new List<Item>()
{
    new Item() { StartTime = DateTime.Today, Name = "item2"},
    new Item() { StartTime = DateTime.Today, Name = "item1"},
    new Item() { StartTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1), Name = "item3"},
};
```

Now the big difference in the 2 queries is where the order by is being performed. In the first query, when you perform `groupedItems.OrderBy(x => x.Name)` its being performed on a `IGrouping<DateTime,Item>` or a single entry as it iterates through all the groupings.

In the second query, the orderby is being performed after the fact. This means you're doing an orderby on a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime,Item>>` because the iterations have already happened.

Since Microsoft was nice they added something to help deal with this for expressions. [This overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549393.aspx) allows you to specify the item returned as it iterates through the collection. Here's an example of the code:

```
var expressionResult = Items.GroupBy(x => x.StartTime, 
(key, grpItems) => new { key, Items = grpItems.OrderBy(y => y.Name) });
```

The second part of the GroupBy you can specify a lambda expression that takes a key and a grouping of items under that key and return an entry that you specify, which is the same as you're doing in the original query.

Hope this helps!